# Intercepting a call disconnects all call legs

Tags: freeswitch

This is the scenario
A call to FS which connects it to B.
B dial an extension(bind_digit), That extension is checked in DB to fetch the Number Associated with Extension.
Then FS calls That number(C).
Now i want to Connect A to C.
here is my sample code

```
ns = freeswitch.Session(dialStr..SIP_TRUNK..number)
while (ns:ready() and dispo ~= 'ANSWER' ) do
    dispo = ns:getVariable("endpoint_disposition")
    os.execute("sleep 1")
end

if (dispo == 'ANSWER') then
    ns:execute("intercept",auuid)
    freeswitch.consoleLog("INFO","Intercepted the call \n")
end
```

but after Intercept all call gets hangup. What i am doing wrong..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops.. i forgot to set ns:setAutoHangup(false). So session was getting destroy after executing last statement of script.